# Simple, but advanced XML-RPC on PHP?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I'm trying to use the Opensubtitles API in my project, but I just can't make it work right. I'm using a wrapper called [Ripcord](http://code.google.com/p/ripcord/), which is ultimately simple and nice to use, but it doesn't support everything. It's easy to use the method [LogIn](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC#LogIn) with it, but when [searching for subtitles](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC#SearchSubtitles), I cannot make it work.

Here's my code in all its simplicity:

```
include('ripcord.php');
$client = ripcord::client('http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc');
$token_from_login = $client->LogIn('username','password','lang','useragent'); //works fine
$get = $client->SearchSubtitles($token_from_login,array('query'=>$search)); //doesn't work
```

The problem must be the the fact that Ripcord doesn't support array. So I'm looking for alternative ways to make calls with ease.

I'm new to XML-RPC so I wish for some constructive help as it seems to be a popular way to make API. I basically need a good example for XML-RPC calls. I cannot understand the PHP's manual. A wrapper/class is not necessary, if it's fairly simple without a one.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Ripcord, it does support arrays, as it uses PHP's xmlrpc_encode which converts it automatically to the 'struct' type.

However your script uses an undeclared variable $search, which isn't filled with anything in this script. Assuming you have a working script which does fill in this variable, you might want to check what response you are getting from the server. You can access that through the $client->_response property, after calling a method. To see the exact xml-rpc request the client made, check the $client->_request property.

Unfortunately I could not check your code further, since opensubtitles.org seems to have some problems right now.

Comment: Thanks for your support! That's right, Opensubtitles' servers are down most of the time. As a matter of fact I made Opensubtitles work on my site, but it was slow enought to cause problems with other stuff. So, I'm not in need of xml-rps right now. However, you can be sure that next time I'm using xml-rpc, I'm using Ripcord, as it's insanely simple and fully functional. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the Zend Framework's xml-rpc client - I don't think it would be much of a hassle. It is very neatly built and I think it will solve the problem with arrays.